# RequestParam validation in Spring 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I'm using spring 3.0.5 for a web application running on Tomcat (Yeah, I know it's very old).
And in my REST methods I'm trying to have my `@RequestParam`s validated in terms of `Min` / `Max` for numeric values, and `MaxLength` for String values.

I'm familiar with the Spring 3.1 `@Validated` annotation, and in my version it doesn't work.
Is there any solution suitable for older spring versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved through JSR 303 / hibernate validator.

Create a Validator instance / create custom validator instance.

As in your case its older version hence you can achieve the same using below documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example instead of text answer?